# Changing e-mail out of Google but keep on using GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Our company uses different Google services (one of them being GCP). We are going to move our e-mail accounts to another mail supplier and we are wondering what the impact will be on the existing GCP services that certain users use. To make it clear our @companyname.com mails are currently hosted by Google and they will be moved to another supplier.

Will the users (identified by their e-mail address) keep on working "seamlessly" with GCP even we do not use Google's mail anymore?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: More clarification is required. What service is hosting your email domain? Are you using those email addresses within your services/applications and/or as identities to authenticate with Google Cloud IAM?

Comment: Hi John. Thanks for your response. The domain is currently hosted by Google and we are going to move it to Microsoft. The answer to your second question is yes for both things.

Comment: 1/2) Your comments do not provide the required details. If you are using Google Workplace for email and for Google Cloud IAM, you will NOT be able to move those identities to another email platform without keeping the Workplace account. The authentication must be handled by a Google account (Gmail, Workplace, Identity Platform).

Comment: 2/2) You can move your email (send/receive) to another platform. It is the authentication/authorization part that must stay with Google. You can have email for your domain hosted by another provider and still keep Google Workplace. Otherwise, you will need to create new Gmail or Identity Platform identities for Google Cloud IAM.

Comment: Thanks John. Well, in fact we will move to Microsoft's Office services as well and, strictly speaking, we only want to keep the GCP services (https://cloud.google.com/) working for specific users identified by their mail address (currently hosted by Google).

Answer (score 1):

Posting this community wiki answer for better usability.

[John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley) wrote:

If you are using Google Workplace for email and for Google Cloud IAM, you will NOT be able to move those identities to another email platform without keeping the Workplace account. The authentication must be handled by a Google account (Gmail, Workplace, Identity Platform).

You can move your email (send/receive) to another platform. **It is the authentication/authorization part that must stay with Google**. You can have email for your domain hosted by another provider and still keep Google Workplace. Otherwise, you will need to create new Gmail or Identity Platform identities for Google Cloud IAM.